# using fiddler to capture web service xml requests

Tags: web-services, soap, port, fiddler

I have a java webapp on localhost:8086 that sends and receives  webservices to localhost:9080.
fiddler only captures traffic on port 8086.

How can i make fiddler (or any other program) capture the webservice request and response

(i am sending objects and i need to inspect the deserialized xml soap request)

Comment: Fiddler is not restricted to port 8086. There's something wrong with your setup. See the Fiddler faq for how to capture local traffic.

Comment: i can capture local web traffic, but i cant capture the webservices,

Comment: There's nothing inherently special about web services. Consider some radical ideas, like maybe the web service isn't sending on the port you think it is, things like that. Again, there's nothing at all special about them.

Comment: i found this , http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-Recording/recording-soap-trafic.html , but i need an example how to set java to send webservices through a proxy or by tunneling

Comment: On AXIS? If so, look [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t132514-how-to-call-a-webservice-through-a-proxy-server-with-java-axis.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [membrane monitor](http://www.membrane-soa.org/http-proxy.htm). They explain in details how to setup a proxy.

Comment: Membrane Monitor is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let your client app connect to "localhost.:8086" (notice the "."), Fiddler can then capture the traffic.